# Stop purging varnish cache in Magento

Tags: magento2

We have Varnish installed on Magento 2.4 and at times our Varnish cache is purged or the varnish is not holding the pages in cache for the mentioned TTL i.e. 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You may try varnishlog (i.e. sudo varnishlog -g request -i requrl) to see if traffic is even coming through varnish.